# Wrong data through Oledb c#

Tags: c#, csv, oledb, oledbconnection

I'm trying to read CSV files through OleDb and C#. I'm able to read most of the files perfectly but only in some cases I'm getting empty cell value(even in this file some cells value are coming but not all) even if value is there. Have any of you faced such issue with oleDB and CSV files?? If yes, then please tell the solution.

Answer (score 2):

OLEDB likes to guess at the data types based on the values found in the first few rows, and anything that doesn't fit that data type after it's guessed comes back null/empty.

So if you had a csv like the following...

```
1,A
2,B
3,C
4,D
5A,E
5B,F
6,G
7,H
```

depending on registry settings (I'm more familiar with this issue for Excel, not sure if it's configured the same way for CSV), OLEDB might read the first 8 records, and decide the first column is numeric because the majority of the data is numeric, and the second is char, and once it sets those data types, if it reads a non-numeric value for that first column, it doesn't throw any error, just returns the value as null.

If this is your issue, I believe you can work around it by using IMEX=1 in your connection string to force mixed data to be read as text, and then when you retrieve the values, I always use GetValue, as opposed to GetString or GetDouble, etc.

Comment: I'm using IMEX=1, in my case complete column is coming as empty

Comment: Might want to try using a schema.ini file.  See this link.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms709353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx  .  Also, you can write some code to output the connection metadata to see what data types are being used